# How to debug Docker containers killed by host (137)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running 3 applications together using docker-compose:

- Standard Nginx image
- Java/Spark API server
- Node.js app (backend + frontend)

I can bring the composed service up with `docker-compose up` no problem, and it runs for a period of time with no issues. At some point something kills the two non-nginx containers with code 137, and the service goes down.

My `docker-compose.yml` has `restart: always` on each container, but as I understand it this will not restart the containers if they're getting killed in this way. I verified this with `docker kill $CONTAINER` on each one, and they are not restarted.

When the application exits, all I see at the end of my logs is:

```
nginx exited with code 0
java_app exited with code 143
node_app exited with code 137
```

How can I debug why the host is killing these containers, and either stop this from happening or make them restart on failure?

Comment: if you are sure that its the system who is killing them, there should be something in system logs... other than that you can check the logs of stopped containers docker ps -a, then docker logs {container-id}

Comment: After the containers exit, they don't appear in `docker ps -a` - is there something to change so that they hang around? I've edited the question with what I see in the `docker-compose` logs.

Comment: If you are attached to docker-compose, that is, if you are running in foreground, all logs from containers should be already be there. But since there isn't anything, you will need to take a look at system logs. Which host are you on?

Comment: What system logs should I be looking at? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You can also pipe the docker output to a file if you need to start it detached`docker-compose up --build >> /var/log/myLogs/log 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 0):

You are not have enough memory or your applications have a memory leak. You can limit each container. Also, you can try to create swap space if you are not have enough memory.

Comment: The containers are well within their memory limits as reported by `docker stats`.